# get data point when user click a line graph using DataVisualization.Charting.Chart

Tags: winforms, charts, indexing, mschart

I am using DataVisualization.Charting.Chart (winform), I need to get the data point index when user clicks on a line graph in MouseDown event.

I know there is a HitTest function accepting x & y, but for a line graph, we only need to verify x, if we scan the y (0 to height of graph), it will work, but the performance is too bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to enable the cursor

```
chartArea1.CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
chartArea1.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
// set selection color to transparent so that range selection is not drawn
chartArea1.CursorX.SelectionColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
```

and handle the CursorPositionChanged event.

```
private void chart1_CursorPositionChanged(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
{
   // find a point (this series only has Y values, so using position as index works
   // for a series with actual X values, you'd need to Find the closest point
   DataPoint pt = chart1.Series[0].Points[(int)Math.Max(e.ChartArea.CursorX.Position - 1, 0)];
   // do what is need with the data point
   pt.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Square; 
}
```

This obviously assumes a single Series in your ChartArea.

Comment: hi, my series has actual x values, it is time based, but the interval is not consistent(fixed). how to find the closest point? can we have the position of all the points so that we can iterate through to find the closest one?

Answer (score 2):

if you are use HitTestResult's ChartElementType.

```
HitTestResult result = chart.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)
{
    int index = result.PointIndex;
    // todo something...
}
```

Comment: I have applied this code in order to showcase the element, in my chart I have multiple values, what I want to do is if I move to another datapoint, erase the "selected event" of the previous data point. Have you ever work on something like that?